# How to Register .Net UserControl as ActiveX VS2012

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, interop, activex

I am trying to create an ActiveX control wrapper for a .NET usercontrol in Visual Studio 2012 using VB.NET.

For reference I am not interested in embedding this in a web page, I want to use it in a VB6 application.

I followed the steps [outlined here](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/general/wrapping-a-net-user-control-as-an-activex.aspx)

- Created a Class Library
- Added a UserControl
- Tick "Make assembly COM Visible"
- Tick "Register for COM Interop"
- I then added the com registration. My usercontrol class now looks like this:

  ```
  <ProgId("TestAx.DummyControl")>
  <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)>

  Public Class DummyControl

  <ComRegisterFunction>
  Public Shared Sub RegisterClass(key As String)
      Dim sb As New StringBuilder(key)
      sb.Replace("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "")

      ' Open the CLSID\{guid} key for write access  
      Dim k As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), True)

      Dim ctrl As RegistryKey = k.CreateSubKey("Control")
      ctrl.Close()

      ' Next create the CodeBase entry - needed if not string named and GACced.  
      Dim inprocServer32 As RegistryKey = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", True)
  inprocServer32.SetValue("CodeBase", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
  inprocServer32.Close()

      k.Close()
  End Sub

  <ComUnregisterFunction>
  Public Shared Sub UnregisterClass(key As String)
      Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(key)
      sb.Replace("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", "")

      ' Open HKCR\CLSID\{guid} for write access  
      Dim k As RegistryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(sb.ToString(), True)

      ' Delete the 'Control' key, but don't throw an exception if it does not exist  
      If k Is Nothing Then Return
      k.DeleteSubKey("Control", False)

      ' Next open up InprocServer32  
      Dim inprocServer32 As RegistryKey = k.OpenSubKey("InprocServer32", True)

      ' And delete the CodeBase key, again not throwing if missing   
      inprocServer32.DeleteSubKey("CodeBase", False)

      ' Finally close the main key   
      inprocServer32.Close()
      k.Close()
  End Sub

  End Class
  ```

I can see the assembly in VB6 when I go to `Project>References` but not when I right click on the Toolbox and select `Components`. If I try and browse to the tlb here I get an error message: "The file xxxx was not registerable as an ActiveX Component"

What have I missed?

Comment: You snipped the important parts.

Comment: @HansPassant - They are as from the sample but converted to vb. I have added them for completeness

Comment: You need to do a lot more work here, at least reproduce *all* of the keys that Regasm.exe writes if you don't use a custom registration function.  You could use SysInternals' ProcMon to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this which was to install VS2010 and install the Forms Interop Toolkit. I then created a new project and selected ActiveX control.

After that I managed to upgrade my project to VS2012 and compile it without issue.

This is not ideal but is only something that needs to be done once.

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem similar to this... how I handled it was to place the .Net code a command line function and call it from VB6.

Comment: I don't understand how that would work - can you give more detail?

Comment: So the new .Net code is put in a command-line project. Any parameters would be passed as command line switches "ex. C:\Myfunction /param1:value /param2:value" - the vb6 code would call it like any other program - using Shell or one of the APIs. If it needs to pass values back, it's a little more tricky - but not impossible. It's definitely a dirty hack - but it worked for me.

Comment: I need an ActiveX control that I can host within an existing VB6 form so this won't work for me.

Comment: @Matt Wilko - I have some other suggestions - but I'm not able to verify that they would work at this time, so I'm hesitant to put them out publicly.